# How to reference app code form a SiriIntent extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, sirikit, ios-targets

I have setup a SiriKit target within my application recently, but I cannot reference any app code within it.

I have added my app's target to the SiriKit target's Build Targets->Target Dependencies section, but I still get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_<CLASSNAME>", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IntentHandler.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Where  is the name of a app class I am trying to reference in the IntentHandler.m class.

I am able to import the app code class I need to use just fine, but if I try to use it in actual code it results in the error.

Everything "seems" fine with the code too, which is odd.  Syntax highlighting works, ctrl+click brings me to the appropriate class, etc, so it's clearly finding the class at some point, just not where it matters most!

My code is like this:

```
#import "IntentHandler.h"
#import "<CLASSNAME.h>

@interface IntentHandler () <INSearchForPhotosIntentHandling>

@end

@implementation IntentHandler

- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent {
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - INSearchForPhotosIntentHandling
- (void)handleSearchForPhotos:(INSearchForPhotosIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(INSearchForPhotosIntentResponse *response))completion {
    NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INSearchForPhotosIntent class])];
    Object test = [[<CLASSNAME> instance] getObjectWithName:@"test"];
    // do stuff with the test Object, which may require me to send the response as INSearchForPhotosIntentResponseCodeFailureRequiringAppLaunch
    // but for now just return INSearchForPhotosIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp.
    INSearchForPhotosIntentResponse *response = [[INSearchForPhotosIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSearchForPhotosIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp userActivity:userActivity];
    completion(response);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the class **Helper.swift** can be access from **my app** and  **extension**. Do as follows.

1.

[image]

2. Go to file inspector in right hand side of Xcode.

[image]

3. My code in extension.

[image]

Note: In obj-c you need to do above steps for .h and .m files.

Comment: Presumably that means any dependencies the Helper.swift file uses will also have to be included to the SiriKitDemoExtension target, right?  Doesn't including the SiriKitDemo as a target dependency include all files included with that target?

Comment: Yes we need to add the dependencies file of Helper.swift  to sirikitDemoExtension target, otherwise it will throw an error.